# Replace negative values of std::vector using signbit in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to replace negative values of a std::vector with another known value using signbit, but it wont work. The failing command is:

```
replace_if(myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), signbit, 999);
```

The error I get is:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘replace_if(std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<int>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’
```

The std::vector is of type int, and from the error output I understand that it didn't find the function? I included "math.h" though.. Maybe signbit does not work with integers?

If this wont work, can you propose an alternative in one line?

Edit:
Because the code is big I made an example which produces the same error.

```
// replace_if example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::replace_if
#include <vector>       // std::vector
#include <cmath>       //  std::signbit

int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector;

  // set some values:
  for (int i=-10; i<10; i++) myvector.push_back(i);              

  std::replace_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), std::signbit, 0); 

  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can I see your whole code?  You might have missed out some things

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you compling `c++1z`?

Comment: @DanielR. I am using g++ with -std=c++11

Comment: @XcoderX The whole code is big so I updated the question with an example that reproduces the error.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? A simple lambda that doesn't convert the argument to a double is a much better choice IMO. Especially since you need a helper to fix the multiple overload issue.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Didn't get your point, did I do a conversion? I just didn't know that the compiler wasn't able to tell which version of the overloaded function had to use.

Comment: `signbit` is for floating point values, and if the value is not already floating point it is cast to a double. That's not free. `return x < 0;` is much easier.

Comment: @RetiredNinja signbit has many overloaded functions, including one for integer inputs.

Comment: @alex Not on my compiler, and not according to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit Not according to your compiler either, otherwise you would not have this problem. Yes, it will work with any integral, however it casts the integral to double. I can think of no reason to use signbit with an integer. There's no NaN, no +-0, no +-inf. No reason you can't just compare against 0 to get the information you need in a supported and efficient way.

Comment: @RetiredNinja So you mean its better to write [](int i){return i <0;}? Sorry, I didn't get your point because I didn't even know about "lambda" functions. Of-course this is simpler and thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error `<unresolved overloaded function type>` tells you that there are
 multiple overloads that could be used, but the compiler does not know which one.

One simple solution would be to use a lambda function instead of passing the function name with multiple overloads

```
std::replace_if (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), [](int i){return std::signbit(i);}, 999);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. So, why the compiler cannot tell which version to use according to what the vector contains?

Comment: @alex: the point is that the overload choice here happens while initializing the `replace_if` argument, before seeing how it's going to be employed. What you expect would require the language to be able to pass multiple overloads together in a single parameter, to be then resolved on the call site. This isn't available in C++, and would also pose multiple problems to how to handle it in the general case.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Thanks, got it!